# Command line arguments are not working

Tags: perl

I am using Perl for the first time.

I am writing two scripts, and one of those is being called from the other.

While I am passing arguments from user input it's giving an error, but if I hard code the values it works fine.

Please advise how to solve.

Code:

**script.pl**

```
use warnings;

my ($choice);

print("Hello!\n");
print("If you want to Generate Add, enter 1.\n");
print("If you want to exit,enter 2.\n");

$choice = <>;
chomp($choice);

if ($choice eq "1") {
  print "Please enter 1st argument:";
  $inputFile = <STDIN>;
  print "Please enter 2nd argument:";
  $outputFile = <STDIN>;

  system($^X, "generateLdifAdd.pl", $inputFile, $outputFile);
}
elsif ($choice eq "2") {
  exit();
}
else {
  print("$choice is an invalid response.\n");
}
```

Comment: I can't see any (attempted) use of command line arguments in the code.

Comment: *"it's giving an error"* isn't very useful information to help us diagnose the problem. You should always show the exact error message in your question. You must *always* `use strict` as well as `use warnings` at the top of your programs.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input:

```
chomp($inputFile = <STDIN>);

chomp($outputFile = <STDIN>);
```

Also, don't forget to include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) at the top of every script along with [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Someone's already mentioned needing to `chomp` your reads from STDIN. 
Would I be right in thinking you've done a `print` on the values you got, and they're all looking good? 
Can I suggest the next port of call is to check what command line you're passing to your second script? 
I would suggest as simple as:

```
print "$^X generateLdifAdd.pl $inputFile $outputFile\n";
```

Check that looks right to you - gotchas might be that your 'other' script isn't in the path. Or that it's not correctly parsing your command line arguments. (You don't give an example, so it's hard to say). This would have also highlighted the problem with not using `chomp` - that your args contain linefeeds.